# Massive problems after updating from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, upgrade, lts

Upon prompt on update I agreed to update to 16.04 LTS - big mistake. Now my system will not boot - And just to really annoy me, although the GRUB menu did make one appearance on the farce of a download, now I can not get that up *either*.

The system now hangs and fails to boot with what I understand is a common failure. What happens is I get the error...

```
'lvmetad is not active yet ... '
```

... then magenta screen, multiple intermediate grey screens, and then shut down.

All the solutions I have seen involve accessing GRUB menu. I have tried everything I know (hold shift, etc.), but the GRUB menu remains elusive.

Any one got any ideas at all as to how I can solve this issue?

Comment: If you have access to another computer, try creating a [Boot-Repair disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Boot-Repair is used to help fix GRUB after it breaks. It offers an automatic repair option, & also  advanced repair.

Comment: After slogging away for hours I think I have solved all the issues but I still can't get flashplayer to work (for GRUB I had to change keyboards to get access - who knew?). I gather I am not alone so i'll wait for the fix. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Using tty or editing GRUB menu**

If you have access to tty/terminal you can edit `/etc/default/grub`.

Alternatively this can be done by editing GRUB menu listing.  To do this, at the boot up start, hold **right** '**SHIFT**', press '**E**' to edit configuration, & then follow step 4.

1. Press CTRL + ALT + F1.
2. Login to user that has root permissions.
3. Enter the command:

> ```
> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
> ```

4. Change the following line...

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```

**to...**

> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
> ```

5. Save the changes, then reboot the system.
6. If that works, then your done! If not follow step 7-9.
7. Repeat step 1-3.
8. Add the following line:

> ```
> GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"
> ```

9. Save the changes, & reboot.
10. **[For Intel]** If GRUB still isn't working, then follow step 11-1
11. Install the following drivers:

> ```
> xserver-xorg-video-intel
> xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg
> ```

---

**Using a boot-repair-disk**

1. [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files) the x86bit or x64bit version of the boot-repair-disk iso.
2. Burn the boot-repair-disk iso to a USB or DVD/CD (unless your pc came w/ Windows8).
3. Insert the USB/CD/DVD. Boot from your USB/CD/DVD.
4. Choose language.
5. If you are able to do so, connect to internet.
6. Choose option ~> "Recommended repair"
7. If that doesn't fix your problem, then try using the advanced option.

---

**Using boot-repair in Ubuntu**

Boot-repair works in Ubuntu & live sessions of Ubuntu.

1. We'll start by installing boot-repair. Run the cmds:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

2. Now run boot-repair w/ the cmd:

> boot-repair

3. Choose option ~> "Recommended repair"
4. If that doesn't fix GRUB, use the "Advanced" option in boot-repair.

---

**Using 'systemctl' cmds**

(This one doesn't really *relate* to GRUB but you can try it!)

If you are using **lvm** and **systemd** enter these commands:

> ```
> systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad.service 
> systemctl enable lvm2-lvmetad.socket
> systemctl start lvm2-lvmetad.service
> systemctl start lvm2-lvmetad.socket
> ```

---

**Links**

- [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki - "Boot-Repair"](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- [Sourceforge - "Boot-Repair"](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)